# Cron doesn't find PHP

Tags: php, cron

I am setting my cronjob as:

```
 */5 * * * * /usr/local/lib/php /home/..app/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php /devices/checkForAlert
```

whereas in checkForAlert function of devices controller i’ve just printed ‘hi’ but mail from cronjob only contains this

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/lib/php: is a directory
```

Can you please tell me that is going wrong here…

Comment: I've tried so many paths for cron_dispatcher.php...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a portable solution you can use `env` :

```
 */5 * * * * /usr/bin/env php /home/..app/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php /devices/checkForAlert
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/local/lib/php: is a directory
```

You have provided the path to a directory called php, rather than the php binary.

Try typing `whereis php` and replacing the above path with the one returned:

```
> whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

For example, that would be `/usr/bin/php` in the above output.